# Can the phrase "one by one " be used independent of time?

Tags: phrase-usage

> Put these balls in the boxes **one by one**.

I created the sentence above to say that **one ball should be put in each box**.

After looking up the meaning in some dictionaries, I am afraid that the usage of "one by one" in the sentence may be incorrect. For example, Collins Online Dictionary explains this phrase as follows:

> [You can use one by one to indicate that people do things or that
>   things happen in sequence, not all at the same time.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/one-by-one)

It doesn't matter to my sentence when the balls are put.

Comment: *One ball should be put in each box* sounds good as is.

Comment: "One ball should be put in each box." This is all you need. "One by one" does not mean that.

Comment: You could also replace your first example by *...in the boxes **one at a time*** - but it would *still* mean the same (during each act of placing a ball in a box you should only put *one* ball in there, but this says nothing about whether you can or should put any more in that box - either immediately, or some time later if you find you have a few balls left over).

Comment: What about "one for each"?